# Eloquent and Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel

Is Laravel Eloquent's save() method essentially doing the Query Builder's job?

Query Builder:

```
DB::table('flights')
    ->where('id', 1)
    ->update(['name' => 'New Flight Name']);
```

Eloquent:

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);
$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';
$flight->save();
```

If that's true, is that the same for Eloquent's `create()`? I was watching Laravel's official video tutorials, and I see the author uses Eloquent's `create()` and `save()` inside the controller. Is that the difference between Query Builder and Eloquent? That we can use Eloquent inside controller?

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, `query builder` and `eloquent methods` are doing the same job, **However** if you use the Eloquent model in general you will be able to use the [Eloquent relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) which  will speed up the development process and make your life easier. with the fact that if you deal with huge data in your database the `query builder` is faster.
- the difference between `save` and `create` is that save accepts a full Eloquent model instance while  create accepts a plain PHP array red the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method).